# How do I find the average of each data_point, within the data frame (df) in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, average

Data Frame (df):

---

### Data_point | Measurement

### a          | 2

### a          | 4

### b          | 6

### b          | 8

### c          | 4

### c          | 10

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense to me. What would the "average of each data point" be?  Also, finding either the mean, median or other statistic of a column of data (if that is what you want) is something you could easily find via either ?mean in R or by searching Google.   Please also read the instructions for asking questions.

Comment: @Elin I know I can use the mean function to find the mean of a column, but I do not want to find the mean of the whole column. I just want to find the mean corresponding to the data point a, then a mean corresponding to the data point b etc.....

Comment: If point a only has one value the mean is that value.  Please edit your question to explain what you mean after reading how to ask a question, how to create a minimum viable example.

Comment: Look up either aggregate or dplyr:: summarize.

Comment: Also just to summarize you need to make it so that someone could copy your code and data and paste it into their R instance and you should include the desired results.

Comment: Elin is right. Next time please read - [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

**Data**

```
Data_point <- c('a','a','b','b','c','c')
Measurement <- c(2,4,6,8,4,10)

df <- data.frame(Data_point=Data_point, Measurement=Measurement)
```

You can make use of `mean` and `which` to choose what values you want. Combining this into a function gives the result you want. As mentioned, there is probably a function already for this (probably somewhere in `tidyverse`), but this is used with just base R.

```
average <- function(x) {
  mean(df$Measurement[which(df$Data_point == x)])
}

sapply(unique(df$Data_point), average)
#[1] 3 7 7
```

Comment: This is a code only answer, you need to explain what you did and why you did it.

Comment: @shique Thank you! Please could you clarify what "x" represents in this case?

Comment: x represents input from the function that is in this code, defined as `average`. Using `sapply`, you can call the function multiple times, with the result from `unique(df$Data_point)` as inputs

Answer (score 0):

as Elin suggests, dplyr can do this. Using the data from Shique:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Data_point) %>% summarise_all(mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

A `base R` option would be `aggregate`

```
aggregate(.~ Data_point, df1, mean)
```